# Refresh Oldschool GUI Design

Tags: user-interface

I'm building Desktop Software for over 10 years now, mostly it's simple Data-Input Software. My problem is, it's always looking the same: A Treeview on the Left and a lot of Text/Data Fields to the right, depending on the type of data currently is worked on. Are there any fresh ideas how such software nowadays should look like?

For further clarification:
It's very hierarchical data, mostly for electronic devices. There are elements of data which provide static settings for the device and there are parts which describe some sort of 'Program' for the device. There are a lot (more than 30) of different input masks. Of course i use combo boxes and Up/Down Entry Fields.

Answer (score 8):

Having all of your software look the same thing is a *good* thing.  One of the best ways to make it easy for people to use your software is to make it look exactly the same as other software your users already know how to use.

There are basically two common strategies for how to handle entry of a lot of data.  The first is to have lots of data entry fields on one page.  The next is to have only a few data entry fields but a lot of pages in a sort of wizard-style interface.  Expert users find the latter much slower to use, as do users who are entering data over and over again.  However, the wizard style interface is less confusing for newer users since it offers fewer elements at once and tends to provide more detail on them.

I do suggest replacing as many text fields as possible with auto-complete-based combo-boxes.  This allows users to enter data exactly the same as with text-boxes, but also allows users to save typing by hitting the down key to scroll through choices after typing part of the data in.

Providing more detail on what data is being entered would probably yield more specific answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also answer with a question, which is to ask what your motivation for considering a change is? Like the other posters, I'd agree that there is some value in consistency, but there's also a strong value in not ignoring niggles-in-the-back-of-the-mind feelings you have. Maybe you have a sense that your users aren't as productive as you'd like them to be, or you've heard feedback to that effect from your customers, or you're just looking to add some innovation for your own interest. Scratching itches is a good trait in a developer, in my view.

One thing I'd advocate would be a detailed user study. How much do you know about what your users do with the interfaces you create? Do you know the key tasks, the overall workflow? Would you know if one task regularly consumed 60% of your users' time, or if there was a task that was only performed once a month? Getting a good sense of what the users actually do (and not what they say they do) is a great place to start thinking about what changes might be worthwhile, especially if you can refactor the task to get a qualitatively different user experience.

A couple of specific alternative designs you might like to include in re-visioning the UI might be be facet browsing (works well for searching and exploring in hierarchies), or building a database of defaults / past responses so that text boxes can use predictive completion. However, I think my starting point would be the user study.

Ian

Answer (score 0):

If it works...

Depending on what you've got happening with the data (that is, is it hierarchical, or fairly flat), you might want to try a tab-based metaphor, or perhaps the "Outlook-style", with a sidebar showing the sections of an application. One other notion I've played with lately is the "Object desktop" that I first saw proposed by Scott Ambler (Building Object Applications That Work). In this, you can display collections of items, or the user can "peel off" individual records for easy access.

Answer (score 0):

Your information is not enough to really suggest you an interface alternative. However, may I answer your question with a question? Why do you think you have to change it? Has your customer complained? If not, it looks like your customer is happy with the way the software works right now, thus I wouldn't change it. If your customer complains about it, he'll most likely not just say "It's bad", he will say "Why can't it look like ..." and this will give you an idea how to change it.

I once had to re-design a very outdated goods management system. The old one was written for a now dead database system, still running in MS-DOS. The customer suggested I should create a prototype how this re-implementation might look like and then he'll decide if I get that job or not. I replaced the old, dead database with a modern MySQL database, I replaced the problematic shared peer access with a client server approach and I chose to rewrite the UI in Java, since different OSes were used and this had the smallest porting costs. So far the concept seemed good, the customer liked it. However, when he asked his employees what they think about it, they asked "So far it's great, but we have one question: Why doesn't it look like the old one?". Actually, it turned out that even with all the modern technologies, they wanted the interface to exactly look and being operated like the old one. So I had to re-build a 1986 usability nightmare MS-DOS UI in Java, because no other UI was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is more about a clean, usable, logical design than anything else.  If your program makes sense to the user, isn't clunky and works as advertised, then everything else UI related is essentially just like painting the house.  I've sometimes rolled out a new version of a program with essentially the same controls that are skinned differently.

There's a reason that you've probably chosen the tree view - because it probably makes really good sense to do so.  There are different containers and controls available in the various UI libraries, depending on the language, but I tend to stick with the familiar because the user probably gets how a tree control works and how a combobox works.

Answer (score 0):

A user interface needs to be usable, just don't do the misstake to change to something working to something fancy-schmancy just because it looks better (been down that road)...

- Make sure that added
  widgets/controls really add a business value
- Make sure that the added
  widgets/controls do not mess up your
  architecture (too much) and makes
  the application harder to
  manage/maintain
- Try to keep platform standards on
  how to do things (for example the [Vista ux guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx))

:)

//W